# How to return Generic T.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Given a definition like so

```
public class KeyValueItem<K,V>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }
    public V Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return T.ToString(); // does not compile
    }
}
```

How do i override ToString() and return V.ToString();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it looks like you want to use:

```
public class KeyValueItem<K,V>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }
    public V Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Value.ToString(); // does compile
    }
}
```

Why?
Because you don't have a T anywhere and K/V are types, not an instance of a type.